# Jsoup nested table parsing not working on search page result table

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I want to parse some data from a table in the result page from a [Google keyword search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vand.png) (https://www.google.com/finance?q=apple&ei=GEiNV9CILMPksAHJmYXQDg)

The search is: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vand.png): https://www.google.com/finance?q=apple&ei=GEiNV9CILMPksAHJmYXQDg (keyword: apple). The result shows share price information of the Apple company and similar companies. I want to parse the table containing share prices.

The html structure is:

[image]

My code is:

```
public static void testGoogle() throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/finance?q=apple&ei=GEiNV9CILMPksAHJmYXQDg").userAgent("Mozzila").get();

    Elements mainbody = doc.select("div.elastic>"
            + "div#app.g-section.g-tpl-left-11p4em>div#gf-viewc.g-unit>div.fjfe-content>div.g-wrap>"
            + "div.g-section.g-tpl-right-1.sfe-break-top-5>div.g-unit>div.g-c.sfe-break-right>"
            + "div#related > div.id-related-table.gf-table > table)");


(Also tried)
//+ "div#related > div.id-related-table.gf-table > table#cc-table.gf-table)");

System.out.println("Html " + mainbody);
}
```

I can get the information up to the div#related part, but the table after that doesn't show. I tried using Chrome css selector and Xpath options to make sure I'm getting the right css path. Would appreciate any advice in case I'm missing the css path or any other reason why jsoup is not parsing from this table. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is the page DOM is changed after it is loaded to the browser using JavaScript.  Jsoup works by parsing the original source code.  It cannot parse the rendered DOM.  In order to parse that table, you need to render the page with something like [HTML Unit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) and then can use Jsoup.

```
    // load page and capture DOM
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    HtmlPage myPage = webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com/finance?q=apple");

    // convert to jsoup document
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myPage.asXml());

    // clean up resources
    webClient.close();

    // select desired data
    Elements rows = doc.select("table#cc-table > tbody > tr");

    for (Element row : rows) {
        String symbol = row.select("td.ctsymbol").text();
        String name = row.select("td.ctname").text();
        String price = row.select("td.rgt").first().text();
        System.out.println(symbol + " " + name + " " + price);
    }
```

**Output**

```
AAPL Apple Inc. 104.14
SNDK SanDisk Corporation 76.18
MSFT Microsoft Corpora... 56.53
SSNNF SAMSUNG ELECTRONI... 0.00000
VZ Verizon Communica... 55.09
HPQ HP Inc 14.15
IBM Intl. Business Ma... 161.72
HTCKF HTC CORPORATION S... 11.82
SNE Sony Corp (ADR) 30.59
GOOGL Alphabet Inc 762.63
WDC Western Digital Corp 53.97
```

Comment: Zack. Thanks one of the most informed answers ever!! It seems to work. Before accepting I wonder if you could confirm my understanding of what's going on (the concept). Jsoup traverses the same DOM to do its parsing. htmlUnit simulates the browser action including changes in the DOM. If that's correct., I don't understand why the DOM change happens in the first place if the URL calls the page RESULT and not the original Google page?

Comment: JSoup parses the source code as delivered from the server.  However, your browser when it receives the same source code it will invoke JavaScript.  Javascript can manipulate the DOM to add/remove.  Notice how the stock prices are constantly changing? There is JavaScript updating the DOM using AJAX to query for the latest price.

Comment: If you compare the source code (right click > view source code) to the rendered code (right click > inspect) you will notice they are different.  HTML Unit allows us to render the source code and fire off the JavaScript so the end result should be the same as what you would see if you inspect the page in your browser.